# iText7 update caused null exception when trying to load pdf file

Tags: vb.net, itext7

I'm using vs2019 vb.net & project framework is 4.7.2
I recently updated iText7 to v7.2.4 from 7.2.1 & suddenly this line
'''
Dim form As PdfAcroForm = PdfAcroForm.GetAcroForm(doc, True)
'''
gave error null exception so I uninstalled 7.2.4 & reinstalled 7.2.1 now I have the following error & I can't find where the reference to 7.2.4 is coming from

> Warning        Found conflicts between different versions of "itext.commons" that could not be resolved.
> There was a conflict between "itext.commons, Version=7.2.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=8354ae6d2174ddca" and "itext.commons, Version=7.2.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=8354ae6d2174ddca".
> "itext.commons, Version=7.2.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=8354ae6d2174ddca" was chosen because it was primary and "itext.commons, Version=7.2.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=8354ae6d2174ddca" was not.
> References which depend on "itext.commons, Version=7.2.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=8354ae6d2174ddca" [C:\Users\Hugh\Documents\Visual Studio 2019\Projects\Points Data System\packages\itext7.commons.7.2.1\lib\net461\itext.commons.dll].
> C:\Users\Hugh\Documents\Visual Studio 2019\Projects\Points Data System\packages\itext7.commons.7.2.1\lib\net461\itext.commons.dll

Can anyone help me resolve this so the code runs correctly again please

Answer (score 0):

Found that it wasn't iText7 causing the issue. I turned on Debugging "Just My Code" as I found others who had similar issues with running the code under VS. I then uninstalled all iText7 NuGet packages & re-installed the latest version 7.2.4
Now the debugger doesn't error out & the data fields extraction works as it did before under VS & when compiled as an installer.
Refer this link. Scroll down to near the end of the page [iText7 break VS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62403090/does-visual-studio-update-break-itext7)